# ¿Como hago para que ejecutar el método vector y distancia de mi clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

no sé como crear 2 puntos y ejecutar los metodos de esta clase en esos 2 puntos, tampoco si estan bien las operaciones.

```
import math

class Punto:
    X = 0
    Y = 0
    
    def __init__(self, X = 0, Y = 0):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
    

    def vector(p1, p2):
        return ((p2.X - p1.X)(p2.Y - p1.Y))
    
    def distancia(p1, p2):
        return sqrt((p1.X - p2.X)**2 + (p1.Y - p2.Y)**2)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Con el puro ánimo de poder entender tu situación e intentar ayudar, te pregunto: Cómo escribiste este código si no sabes cómo funciona ni cómo probarlo?

Comment: hola, pues me han mandado una tarea y he seguido los pasos de crear la clase y esos métodos, el problema es que no se como probar los métodos, e intentado de varias maneras y ninguna me funciona.

Comment: Siempre sera mejor incluir en la pregunta las formas en las que no te funcionó, así los demás pueden explicarte por qué no funciona así :) Inténtalo, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/437780/edit) tu pregunta y añade esa información.

Answer (score 0):

#### ¿Cómo crear 2 puntos?

La clase `Punto` tiene definido un método `__init__`, este método ["magico"](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) se ejecuta siempre al inicializar un nuevo objeto de la clase, particularmente en este caso se define como `def __init__(self, X = 0, Y = 0)`, lo cual nos dice dos cosas importantes:

- El objeto se define con dos valores numéricos, se entiende que son los valores de `X` e `Y` que definen un `Punto`
- Ambos parámetros tienen un valor por defecto, por lo que podremos definir el `Punto` de varias formas:

  ```
  p1 = Punto(1,2)   # (1, 2)
  p1 = Punto()      # (0, 0)
  p1 = Punto(1)     # (1, 0)
  ```

#### ¿Están bien las operaciones?

Casi. Dos cosas importantes que veo:

1. `vector()` tiene lo que creo que es un error tipográfico, entiendo te falta una coma en `return ((p2.X - p1.X)(p2.Y - p1.Y))`, debiera ser en realidad: `return ((p2.X - p1.X), (p2.Y - p1.Y))`
2. Como buena práctica, el primer parámetro de los métodos de una clase se lo suele llamar `self`, por ejemplo `def vector(p1, p2)` por `def vector(self, p2)`, esto denota al propio objeto en sí. De todas formas esto no impacta en la funcionalidad.

#### ¿Cómo ejecutar `vector`  y `distancia`?

Estos son métodos del objeto `Punto` por lo que una forma será partir de alguno de los dos puntos, para obtener el vector y la distancia con el otro punto:

```
# Creamos los dos objetos Punto
p1 = Punto(3, 2)
p2 = Punto(3, 3)
   
# Invocamos lo métodos
p1.vector(p2)
p1.distancia(p2)
```

¿Por qué si es `def vector(p1, p2)`, la llamada se hace: `p1.vector(p2)`? por que Python se encarga de hacer esta traducción de forma transparente, y por debajo, lo que se termina haciendo y que eventualmente podría ser la otra forma de invocar los métodos:

```
Punto.vector(p1, p2)
Punto.distancia(p1, p2)
```